# JSON output formatting in Python

Tags: python, json, formatting, large-language-model

I need help with a `LLM` project that I am working on. The `LLM` generates a feedback response and my task is to format the output to `JSON`. I have written the basic structure of the code that uses a `regular expression` to `fetch` `heading(issue)`, `node_ids`, `detailed_description` from the textual data to output into a formatted `JSON`. While this `python` code extracts the relevant information, the formatting is not right. Can someone help me resolve this issue?

```
import re
import os
import json
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize

def extract_data(text):
    section_pattern = r'\d+\.\s\*(.*?)\((Node ID:.*?)\).*?((?=\d+\.\s*\*)|$)|\-\s(.*?)\n\n'
    section_regex = re.compile(section_pattern, re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
    
    matches = section_regex.findall(text)
    data = []
    # print(matches)
    
    for match in matches:
        heading = match[0].strip()
        node_ids = re.findall(r'\d+:\d+', match[1])
        detailed_desc = extract_detailed_desc(match[3].strip())
        data.append({
                'issue': heading,
                'node_ids': node_ids,
                'detailed_feedback': detailed_desc
                })

    return data

def extract_detailed_desc(text):
    
    sentences = sent_tokenize(text)
    detailed_desc = []
    for sentence in sentences:
        detailed_desc.append(sentence.strip('-').strip())
    return detailed_desc


def main():
    txt_file_path = "./FormatOutput/sample.txt"

    if os.path.exists(txt_file_path):
        try:
            with open(txt_file_path, 'r') as txt_file:
                data = txt_file.read()
                # print(data)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error occurred while reading the text file:", e)
    else:
        print("File not found:", txt_file_path)

    structured_data = extract_data(data)
    json_data = json.dumps(structured_data, indent=4)
    print(json_data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The desired output should look something like this:

```
    [
      {
        "issue": "Content Clarity and Structure",
        "node_ids": ["117:55", "117:135"],
        "detailed_feedback": [
          "Combine the text into a clear paragraph explaining the service's purpose, benefits, functionality, and value proposition.",
          "Refine the mission statement to directly address customer pain points the service solves."
        ]
      },
      {
        "issue": "Call to Action (CTA) Optimization",
        "node_ids": ["117:38", "117:89"],
        "detailed_feedback": [
          "Revise the 'BUY NOW' CTA to include the service name or offer (e.g., 'Get [Service Name] Now').",
          "Modify CTAs to create urgency: 'Start Free Trial Today' & 'Secure Your System Now'.",
          "Streamline CTAs by combining similar actions and differentiating trial and purchase options.",
          "Adjust 'DOWNLOAD FREE' button color for better visibility (lighter shade or contrasting color)."
        ]
      },
      {
        "issue": "Headline and Introduction Enhancement",
        "node_ids": ["117:27"],
        "detailed_feedback": [
          "Increase headline text size and weight for prominence on the product image.",
          "Use bullet points with larger font size or contrasting color to highlight features."
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Comment: The desired formatting is inconsistent -- some lists are displayed with all their items on one line, and some are displayed with one line per item.

Comment: Also, json isn't really meant to be a nice human-readable format.  Why do you care about small details of formatting?

Comment: The project pipeline I am working on utilizes the JSON in this specific format.

Comment: json does not care about format.  json is json.  as long as the data is in legal json format, it should not matter.

Comment: Are you saying you have some component that claims to read json, but it fails if the json isn't in this specific format?

Comment: In any case, it seems the format you want is quite specific to your business rules, so I think your only option is to write the file yourself.

Comment: You mean write the file manually?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the structure of the code. Now it is giving output in right formatting.

```
import re
import os
import json
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize


txt_file_path = "./FormatOutput/sample.txt"

if os.path.exists(txt_file_path):
    try:
        with open(txt_file_path, 'r') as txt_file:
            data = txt_file.read()
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error occurred while reading the text file:", e)
else:
    print("File not found:", txt_file_path)

issue_regex = re.compile(r'\*(.*?)\(Node ID:.*?\)')
node_id_regex = re.compile(r'\(Node ID: (.*?)\)')
feedback_regex = re.compile(r'- (.+?)(?=\n\w|$)', re.DOTALL)

matches = issue_regex.findall(data)
node_ids = node_id_regex.findall(data)
feedback_matches = feedback_regex.findall(data)

json_data = []
for i, match in enumerate(matches):
    issue = match.strip()
    feedback = feedback_matches[i].strip()
    detailed_feedback = [sentence.strip()[2:] if sentence.startswith("- ") else sentence.strip() for sentence in sent_tokenize(feedback)]
    issue_data = {
        "issue": issue,
        "node_ids": node_ids[i].strip().split(" & "),
        "detailed_feedback": detailed_feedback
    }
    json_data.append(issue_data)

json_output = json.dumps(json_data, indent=2)
print(json_output)
```